# getdrawingcache() not return rotate view

Tags: android

I rotate a view by an angle. I want to get bitmap from this view. I am getting bitmap by calling `getdrawingcache()`, but not getting rotating view by an angle. It is giving a view without rotating.

Comment: I am using following code:

private void captureUsingDrawingCache(){
     
     targetView.buildDrawingCache();
     Bitmap b1 = targetView.getDrawingCache();
     
     Bitmap b = b1.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);
     BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(b);
     canvasView.setImageDrawable(d);
     targetView.destroyDrawingCache();
    }

Comment: Do not add code in comment. Instead edit the question with this code.

Comment: check out my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254577/how-can-i-take-screenshot-of-rotated-textview-with-emoji/43116641#43116641

Answer (score 0):

For rotation view use this:

```
view.setRotation(45);
```

But your API must be higher than 11

Comment: I already rotate a view. I am trying to get bitmap after rotate a view.

Comment: My minSdkVersion="16" and  android:targetSdkVersion="22"

Comment: Try to call `getDrawingCache()` from parent view which include our rotated view

Comment: If i call getDrawingCache() from parent view, than it will create bitmap for all views containing in parent view. Is it possible to create bitmap of only targeted view which is rotated by an angle?

Comment: ya, I think  it is right solution: wrap your rotated-view to layout, and then call getDrawingCache() from this layout.

Comment: @walkmn rotating parent layout doesn't help either.