# How can i take screenshot of rotated TextView with emoji?

Tags: android, bitmap, textview, screenshot, emoji

I'm trying to make a screenshot of the rotated TextView which contain emoji icons. But on resulting bitmap i see that emoji are not rotated! Why is this happening? How can i make a screenshot with rotated emoji ?

What i expect:

[image]

And this is what i get:

[image]

I'm using this method to get screenshot of view:

```
layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
layout.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = null;
if (layout.getDrawingCache() != null)
    bitmap = layout.getDrawingCache().copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);
layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
layout.destroyDrawingCache();
```

**Update:**
as i figured, if I set `textView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);` then emoji will not be rotated even in the TextView (if you rotate TextView - they will not be rotated, they will be just moving around like a carousel), but still I don't really understand why is this happening, or rotation of emoji (on first picture) is only because of hardware acceleration?

Comment: Please post your xml

Comment: there're no xml, view is created and added to 'RelativeLayout' on runtime

Comment: @AlexanderAgeichenko did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @gbhall no, this question is  still open

Comment: @AlexanderAgeichenko I have the same issue.

Comment: @AlexanderAgeychenko how do you rotate the view? An animation or setRotation?

Comment: @SoftDesigner in onTouch callback, calculating angle from center of view and setting resulting angle to setRotation() method

Comment: @AlexanderAgeychenko I'm trying to achieve something similar. What I'm thinking about is covering text view into bitmap and then rotate it. Because none of the methods worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i couldnt find a way to solve this really annoying issue, so i had to hack it a bit.
imageviews works perfectly with rotation.
so i basically do all the manipulations with image view - and setting it's image out of the emoji text i want using this method:

```
private Bitmap generateBitmapFromText(int size, String res) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
    tv.setText(res);
    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 150f);
    tv.setTextColor(0xffffffff);
    tv.measure(size, size);
    int questionWidth = tv.getMeasuredWidth();
    int questionHeight = tv.getMeasuredHeight();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(questionWidth, questionHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    tv.layout(0, 0, questionWidth, questionHeight);
    tv.draw(c);
    return bitmap;
}
```

and then i call

```
    Bitmap bitmap = generateBitmapFromText(stickersStartingSize, res);
    imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```